# Adding fastapi routes to WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, fastapi

I am new to WordPress. I wanted to know can I make a WordPress site and then write FastAPI routes for interacting with database and inferencing AI model and similar, then add this to WordPress site?

I am an ML engineer and I don't know a lot about WordPress capabilities.

I want to have a bunch of user and I want to save their activity into database then read data from database and use that to inference AI model. And show results to user. I want to know is it even possible to add such routes to CMS system like WordPress and if it is possible can I use FastAPI for that?

Comment: No, directly integrating FastAPI (Python) and Wordpress (PHP) won't be a real possibility. They'd have to be separate applications that could talk to each other if necessary. You can extend Wordpress, but if you want that code to live inside Wordpress, it'd be better suited as PHP code using the Wordpress API. You might not need Wordpress or a secondary FastAPI server depending on your actual use case, or you can make Wordpress contact your FastAPI server to get any predictions from your models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i write FastAPI app seperately how can i make it talk to wordpress? there should be something like a sql data base in the middle?

Comment: You'd usually use HTTP(s) to exchange data, using `curl` (recommended) or `file_get_contents` in PHP. Let Wordpress handle whatever it needs to handle. However, I'm not sure why you'd actually need Wordpress in the mix, your use case doesn't seem to match directly up with what a CMS is used for?